Given an absolute path to java.exe How to determine if it is JDK or JRE
I wish to determine if absolute path to java executable is from a JDK or JRE.
I tried the below command on bin/java under JDK as well as JRE
/bin/java -XshowSettings:properties -version
But the output is same apart from the  user.dir
user.dir = /home/wladmin/goodbadjdk/jdk1.8.0_411/bin
vs
user.dir = /home/wladmin/goodbadjdk/jdk1.8.0_411/jre/bin
One difference i could find is that the JRE folder has folder structure  /home/wladmin/goodbadjdk/jdk1.8.0_411/jre/lib/security which the JDK does not have.
Other difference is that JDK has /home/wladmin/goodbadjdk/jdk1.8.0_411/bin/javac but JRE does not.
Nevertheless, what would be an ideal way to determine in the given path to bin/java is JRE or JDK?

I would have thought checking for javac should work. The java.exe for my JDK22 and a runtime generated from that JDK with jlink are identical.

Use class ProcessHandle – available since Java 9.
ProcessHandle ph = ProcessHandle.current();
ProcessHandle.Info info = ph.info();
System.out.println(info.command()
                       .orElse("Command not found."));

When I run the above code from my Eclipse 2024-03 on Windows using JDK 17, I get:
C:\Users\USER\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.10.v20240120-1143\jre\bin\javaw.exe

So looks like it using jre and not jdk.

The presence of Java compiler tool might give you a way to determine whether the current JVM is a runtime (eg from jlink) versus a JDK:
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
public class HasJavaC {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean javac = checkForJavaCompiler();
        System.out.println("javac="+javac);
    }

    private static boolean checkForJavaCompiler() {
        try {
            return ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() != null;
        }
        catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

When run with JDK this prints javac=true, whereas with a JRE it prints javac=false.
You could also try checking the available modules with a script (Java 9+ only):
java --list-modules | grep java.compiler

